# An equivalence related to the series in Spitzer's condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be any random walk. The following statement is usefully referred to as Spitzer's condition:

There exists $\rho \in (0,1)$ such that
$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_n > 0 ) \to \rho. \qquad (1) $$

Now, it is said that the above is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_n \geq 0 ) \to \rho, \qquad (2)$$
because $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} P(S_n = 0) < \infty \qquad (3)$$
always holds true. I don't understand how (3) implies the equivalence of (1) and (2). I think I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: I am unable to find a clear reference on Spitzer's condition. Are you sure you have $(1)$ and $(2)$ stated correctly?  The LHS of $(1)$ and $(2)$ are simply $P(S_n > 0)$ and $P(S_n \geq 0)$, since the summands are independent of $k$.

Comment: I presume you meant it to be $S_{k}$?

Comment: Yes, both of you are correct. I wrote $S_n$ instead of $S_k$, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that:
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_k \geq 0 ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_k > 0 ) + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_k = 0 )$$
Thus, (1) and (2) are equivalent if:
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_k = 0 ) \rightarrow 0$$
So, let's use (3) to prove this.

---

Equation (3) implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a sufficiently large $M$ such that:

$$\sum_{k=M}^\infty \frac{1}{k} P(S_k = 0 ) < \epsilon/2$$

Then, we can find a $N$ sufficiently large that for all $n>N$:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^M P(S_k = 0 ) < \epsilon/2$$

Therefore, for all $n > N$:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n P(S_k = 0 ) &< \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^M P(S_k = 0 ) + \sum_{k=M}^\infty \frac{1}{k} P(S_k = 0 ) \\
&< \epsilon
\end{align}$$